# Cannot replace the newline character (\\n) in the text of a label in kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am working on my new app and I want to print the text of a Label and the text of that Label contains newline character (\\n)
so the printed text is also in two lines... but i want to print it in only one line ..So i used `replace ()`.But it is not working
I don't know what is wrong with this ,
I just want to remove the newline character (\\n) while printing the text
Here's the code

````
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
    
    

kv = '''
    
mylayout:
        
    my_label: my_label
        
    MDLabel:
        id: my_label
        text: "general \\n board"
        
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "print"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.5,"y":0.5}
        on_press: root.func()
    
    
    
'''
    
    
    
    
class mylayout(MDFloatLayout):
        
    def func(self):
            
        text = self.my_label.text
            
        print(text.replace("\\n", "+"))
    
    
class test_app(MDApp):
        
        
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
    
    
test_app().run()```
````

Comment: change `"\\n"` to `"\n"`

Comment: if i change `\\n` to `\n` then it doesn't work with Label, It doesn't apply the newline character .. it gives an error.

Comment: not in your kivy  doc... in your `replace` method.  it should be `text.replace('\n', '+')`